# Where can I start learning how to style the HTML5 Video and Audio elements?

Tags: video, audio, html

How would I style the HTML5 Audio and Video and how do I use  the API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://videojs.com - makes it easy to style up the HTML5 video player using only CSS. I've worked with it in the past and it's really easy to get started with.

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/  - This article from Opera goes into great detail about the whole spec, encoding, etc and has a really in-depth article on creating your own controls by adding Javascript listeners. Not for the novice, but adds a great amount of control and flexibility (search for "roll my own controls", it's about halfway down the page).